# Duplicate disk shows in explorer, not in disk management

Tags: windows, partitioning, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a case where a duplicate of one of my drive somehow gets listed in my file explorer.
As per below, the file explorer and get-psdrive will show an H: drive that is the same as K:
Also this H: drive doesn't show in HKLM>SYSTEM>MountedDevices

I logged in with a new users and the letter doesn't appear right away, somehow this H: drive will show up after a few minutes after log in.

Also doing file activities, on one or the other does show up on the other...so yes it is the same drive.

FYI, this computer is a windows 2008R2

What could this be?!?

```
> get-psdrive -PSProvider filesystem

WARNING: column "CurrentLocation" does not fit into the display and was removed
.

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----
A                                      FileSystem    A:\
C                  78.46         57.51 FileSystem    C:\
D                  31.38        268.61 FileSystem    D:\
E                                      FileSystem    E:\
F                 521.57        178.43 FileSystem    F:\
H                 127.25         72.75 FileSystem    H:\
K                 127.25         72.75 FileSystem    K:\
L                1125.65        174.35 FileSystem    L:\


PS C:\Users\Administrator> diskpart

Microsoft DiskPart version 6.0.6002
Copyright (C) 1999-2007 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: XXXXX

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status      Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  ----------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online       136 GB      0 B
  Disk 1    Online       300 GB      0 B
  Disk 2    Online      1300 GB      0 B
  Disk 3    Online       700 GB      0 B
  Disk 4    Online       200 GB      0 B

DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     E                       CD-ROM          0 B  No Media
  Volume 1     C                NTFS   Partition    136 GB  Healthy    System
  Volume 2     D   Shadow_Copi  NTFS   Partition    300 GB  Healthy
  Volume 3     L   Clients   NTFS   Partition   1300 GB  Healthy
  Volume 4     F   Files_Se  NTFS   Partition    700 GB  Healthy
  Volume 5     K   VM        NTFS   Partition    200 GB  Healthy
```

Comment: In disk management if you right click on the drive and choose 'Change Drive Letters and paths' you don't see multiple drive letters assigned right?

Comment: no - just the k: letter. Again from disk man (or diskpart) I do not see that h: drive.

Comment: My guess is the drive letter is somehow being created by Subst.  Try running `subst` without any arguments and see if it lists the H: drive.

Comment: subst returns nothing.